# Give Users permissions to groups in Project Server running in Sharepoint permission mode programmatically

Tags: 2016, project-server

Is there any way to add a user permission to groups in Project server 2013 or 2016 running in SharePoint Permission mode using CSOM or PSI?

Currently we are using ProjectServer.svc For Project server 2016.